# How to dynamically set the Title of SiteMap from MasterPage?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

In My Web.sitemap I have the following:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Groups/ViewGroups.aspx" urlRoute="groups/{PostId}/{PostTitle}" />
</siteMapNode>
```

In my MasterPage I have implemented the **ItemDataBound** event to try and set the title of each page that implements the master page dynamically but for some reason the title is not being set.

```
protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound(object sender, SiteMapNodeItemEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentNodeTitle = GetTitleFromDatabase();

    if (e.Item.ItemType == SiteMapNodeItemType.Current) {
         e.Item.SiteMapNode.Title = CurrentNodeTitle;
    }
}
```

I also tried this in the ItemCreated event but still it did NOT work.

If I set the title in the Web.sitemap then it works perfectly but when I set it using **e.Item.SiteMapNode.Title = CurrentNodeTitle;** the title is nto being set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private string currentKey = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Key
protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentNodeTitle = GetTitleFromDatabase();

    if (e.Item.DataPath == currentKey){
         e.Item.Text = CurrentNodeTitle;
    }
}
```

Edit note:

it should be MenuEventArgs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but e.Item does not have a DataPath property.

Comment: Changing it to MenuEventArgs changes the signature so it's no longer finds the delegate: Here's the error: CS0123: No overload for 'SiteMapPath1_ItemDataBound' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapNodeItemEventHandler'

Comment: No I'm using the SiteMapPath Control.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any way to change it directly for sitemappath. You probably need to use custom attribute with javascript to change it after page load.

Comment: Downvoted.  This answer should be deleted as it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about 6 years old now, and the one answer is completely wrong and should probably be deleted.  I had a hard time finding the answer - it's not nearly as straight forward as I would have expected it to be, but the answer is pretty simple nonetheless.

Using the **static** `SiteMap` classes `SiteMapResolve` event from the `System.Web` namespace (NOT your instance of SiteMapPath!) you can manipulate the URL and Title on the fly.

In my case, I have a custom localization method that retrieves the localized strings from a database.  The sitemap title's contain the key used to identify the string.  This is the code behind for my Master Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += (o, args) =>
    {
        if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null)
            return null;

        SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
        currentNode.Title = SessionObject.LocalizeText(currentNode.Title);

        SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;
        while (tempNode.ParentNode != null)
        {
            tempNode = tempNode.ParentNode;
            tempNode.Title = SessionObject.LocalizeText(tempNode.Title);
        }

        return currentNode;
    };

    // ...
}
```

Then in your Master Page ASPX (or presumably any ASPX page that utilizes this Master Page), you can add `<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" ... />` and it should be processed by the SiteMapResolve event.